# Xamarin Forms push notification not showing up in Android notification bar

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have a weird problem. I have a clean Xamarin Forms project using [Plugin.FirebasePushNotification](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.FirebasePushNotification) which is working flawless on iOS. The wierd problem is that it is working on Android as well, OnNotificationReceived is triggered when I send a push from Postman or Firebase however nothing shows up in the notification bar nor does any push sound.

I have tried closing the app yet noting, and I have also tried to "kill" the app but same thing happends. Only when I have app in debug mode I can see the OnNotificationReceived is actually beeing triggered with the message I've sent so there is nothing wrong with my sending payload.

**MainActivity.cs (Android-project)**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs  (Shared-project)**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Register for push
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("TESTINGPUSH");
    }
```

Comment: you need to wait 2 days before accepting it as an answer (or at least I have to). Maybe you can do it for me?

Comment: Only you can accept your answer. I have no authority to accept your answer. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

although I did use the correct permission in my manifest.xml it didnt take it into account.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

I did an override in MainActivity and it started to work as expected.

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        const int requestLocationId = 0;

        string[] notiPermission =
        {
            Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
        };

        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;

        if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            this.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestLocationId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this works? I have implemented the same and request permisison is executed but popup is not showing. Tested in both real device and emulator in android 13

Comment: yes, this still works for me on Android 13. Note, remove "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>" from your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the code from onstart and added in Oncreate of main activity. What caused the issue was, In main activity oncreated i already have  

```ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 200); ```. When i add the post notification request after this it doesn't work. When I add before this its working even through the storage permissions are not used for android 13